# #How to Filter the palindrome numbers in the given tuple and save it in the tuple

Tags: python

How to Filter the palindrome numbers in the given tuple and save it in the tuple ?

My code :

```
w = (10,11,12,21,22,101,123,111,152)

for i in w:
    if i[:]==i[-1:]:
        print(i)

Error : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-b2b3cfdef377> in <module>
      7 
      8 for i in w:
----> 9     if i[:]==i[-1:]:
     10         print(i)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot use indices for integer values.

1. `i[:]` does **not** work.
2. `str(i)[:]` works.

Also `str(i)[:]` is the same thing with `str(i)` and `str(i)[-1:]` only takes the last digit of the number.

If you want to get the number reversed you have to use `str(i)[::-1]`.

This should work just fine :

```
w = tuple(i for i in w if str(i) == str(i)[::-1])
print(w)
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for a better understanding of the slicing operator:

Comment: This is what I was looking for.. Slicing an integer value ! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Convert your integer to a string. Also, you weren't using the inverse slicing of the string correctly

```
w = (10,11,12,21,22,101,123,111,152)

for i in w:
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
11
22
101
111
```

You also mention that you want to save the result in a tuple. Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) for that:

```
tuple(i for i in w if str(i) == str(i)[::-1])
```

Output:

```
(11, 22, 101, 111)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out ! (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
w = (10,11,12,21,22,101,123,111,152)
for i in w:
    if str(i)[:]==str(i)[::-1]: 
        print(i)
```